# Columns 2D tenson times rows 2D tensor equals a 3d pytorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

Given 2 tensors 2-D in PyTorch `A` (a X m) and `B` (m X b), is there any efficient way to obtain a tensor `C` (m X a X b), where `C[i,:,:] = A[:,i] @ B[i,:]`?

Here I will give an example of the problem:

```
A = torch.FloatTensor([[1,2],[3,4]])
B = torch.FloatTensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

Result:

```
C = torch.FloatTensor([[[1,2,3],[3,6,9]],[[12,15,18],[16,20,24]]])
```

I have done it using a for-loop. However, it is very inefficient.

Comment: are you sure your `C` is correct?

Answer (score 0):

look at [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html#torch.einsum):

```py
C = torch.einsum('im,mj->mij', A, B)
```